# How to write HttpResponseMessage through middleware in aspnetcore 3.1

Tags: c#, middleware, httpresponsemessage

I have an middleware which executes based on specific routing and redirects the request to call another service and the response of the service call need to be sent back to the caller.

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
       return GetServiceDataAsync(context);
    }

    private async Task<object> GetServiceDataAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = service.GetDataAsync();

        return await response;
    }
```

When executing this call, I do see the service call returns response properly. But, the response is not written back as HttpResponseMessage so the caller can read again from the body.

In this case, the response was already read and converted to response. Need some pointers on how to provide the same response back to the caller. With this code, I'm seeing 200 status code, but the body is empty. TIA !

Comment: If the body is empty in means the other side of the connection did not add a body.  You are using HTTP Protocol where a client sends a request, the server receives the request,  the server sends a response, and finally the client receives the response.  A Controller Parses the received message (either on server or client) and the Task are the rules for parsing the received message.  So when you fail the parsing on the receive end either the received message was not sent or the received message doesn't adhere to the expected format of the received message.

Comment: Makes sense. The call to other service in this case (service.GetDataAsync()) already read the httpresponsemessage and converted the response to Task<object> and returning back successfully. But, the same response is not being added to the body which explains the why the body is missing to the caller.